# How to get records with the same specific column content from a DataTable using LINQ

Tags: c#, datatable, duplicates

I have a table with personal data which looks something like this:

```
 Identifier Name Phone Address
 .............................
     1       aa    23    abc
     2       bb    22    abd
     2       cc    11    aaa
     3       dd    44    amd
     4       fa    33    agd
     2       ds    14    dad
     3       as    55    fgg
```

I want to get the records with the same identifier, using LINQ, to get something like this

```
 Identifier Name Phone Address
 .............................
     2       bb    22    abd
     2       cc    11    aaa
     2       ds    14    dad
     3       dd    44    amd
     3       as    55    fgg
```

I could order by Identifier and copy to a new DataTable, then parse it and get the records with the same identifier, but that would be expensive i guess. Is there a shorter way ?
 Thank you !

Comment: Can we have some code, please? What have you tried? When you say 'datatable' are you referring to the `System.Data.DataTable`? Or a text file with data in the format you've provided?

Comment: Yes, it is a System.Data.DataTable. I didn;t post any code because it is big and i have completely different columns. I already extracted duplicates, then i was thinking of making a difference between the data tables, but i couldn;t figure it out. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Something like the code below would filter and extract the duplicates to a new DataTable with the same schema. Code assumes `Identifier` is an `int`. Replace with the appropriate names and types, as applicable.

```
var extractedDuplicates = (from row in table.AsEnumerable()
                           group row by row.Field<int>("Identifier") into rows 
                           where rows.Count() > 1
                           from row in rows
                           select row).CopyToDataTable();
```

Give it a try and see how far that gets you. If there is any chance there aren't any duplicates, you will want to split this into multiple statements, as `CopyToDataTable()` will throw if there are no rows to copy.

```
var duplicateRows = from row in table.AsEnumerable()
                    group row by row.Field<int>("Identifier") into rows 
                    where rows.Count() > 1
                    from row in rows
                    select row;

DataTable extractedDuplicates;
if (duplicateRows.Any())
    extractedDuplicates = duplicateRows.CopyToDataTable();
else
    extractedDuplicates = table.Clone();
```

And, of course, if you do not need a new DataTable, omit the second portion of this code entirely and just work with `duplicateRows`.

Answer (score -1):

```
select * from YourTable a where a.Identifier in 
(
     select aa.Identifier from YourTable aa group by aa.Identifier 
     having (count(aa.Identifier ) > 1)
)
```